# When should I use a MobX observable instead of a React state variable?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm a bit confused. I usually use observables for all the variables that affect what is rendered. But is that the correct way? When should I use state instead of an observable?

Comment: Usually you use `useState` for Local/Internal Component state and `observables` for both Local and Shared (by multiple components) state

Comment: so if a state us local only, then I use state instead of mobx observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends!

Usually you have external (shared, global or whatever you call it) state as `observable` values (they are often called stores, you can make them with classes or pure object or with something else like mobx-state-tree).

And local store is handled with "default" React way such as `useState` or `useReducer` for functional component, or `state` and `setState` for classes.

But sometimes it is very convenient to use MobX for local state too, for such cases there is a hook `useLocalObservable` so you can continue to write everything in MobX way:

```
import { observer, useLocalObservable } from "mobx-react-lite"

import { useState } from "react"

const TimerView = observer(() => {
    const timer = useLocalObservable(() => ({
        secondsPassed: 0,
        resetTime() {
            this.secondsPassed = 0
        }
        increaseTimer() {
            this.secondsPassed++
        }
    }))
    return <span onClick={timer.resetTimer}>Seconds passed: {timer.secondsPassed}</span>
})
```

Although this way might somehow interfere with React Suspense in the future, so it is not recommended for everyone unless you sure you will be fine with it. More about it here: https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#you-might-not-need-locally-observable-state